# How do I remove Error. My logic for notcontains is flawed

Tags: powershell

I build an array of objects and I am interested in recording if there is an error.
Array of objects starts out like this

```
[array]$UsersResults = $GSuspend | ForEach-Object {
    gam update user $_.primaryEmail archived on | Out-Null
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        Email = $_.primaryEmail
        Error = $LASTEXITCODE
    }
}
```

I simply want to know if any error is not 0.

If every error is 0. Later down my script I remove the error column from the array but I am pretty sure the following logic below is flawed.

```
If (-not ($UsersResults.error -notcontains 0)) {
```

Is there a simple way for me to find a error number above 0 or only add error to the array in the top part of the script if an error is found?

Comment: You mean you want something like this? `if($UsersResults |Where-Object Error -ne 0){ "There's at least 1 error!" }`

Comment: Gah!! Yeah that is what I want.. Go ahead and make that an answer @MathiasR.Jessen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Where-Object` to filter the array based on the value of the `Error` column:

```
$failedResults = $UsersResults |Where-Object Error -ne 0

if($failedResults.Count -gt 0){
    Write-Warning "'$($failedResults.Count)' errors occurred!"
}
else {
    Write-Host "No errors occurred!"
}
```

If you want the result to just be a flat array of Email adresses, use `$UsersResults.Email` or `$UsersResults |ForEach-Object Name`. If you want a new array of objects with the `Email` property preserved, but no `Error` property, use `$UsersResults |Select-Object Email`